# MVC webapp update client when database record changed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

What method should I use to update some client side HTML when a database record change is triggered (MVC app)

Comment: This is a push notification scenario. You might take a look at libraries which support this, for example [SignalR](https://www.asp.net/signalr)

Answer (score 2):

Your question is very vauge. Here is solution for sql server and mvc (you can use similar concept with other technologies also). You can create SQLDependency 
and for any change in sql record. Send notification using signalR (push notification from server). Process signalR message in client to update your html.

```
// code to create dependency
    SqlDependency dependency=new SqlDependency(command);  

    dependency.OnChange+=new  
       OnChangeEventHandler(OnDependencyChange); 


private void OnDependencyChange(object sender,   
   SqlNotificationEventArgs e )  
{  
  // Send notification using signalR for push changes from server to client 
}
```

If you working with any other database you will have to write code to monitor change in DB record (depending on database used)

Hope this helps.

For more details

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9x04ed2(v=vs.110).aspx

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/signalr/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-signalr